# How can I take print driver settings by each user and ensure those settings remain intact no matter what machine they use on the network?

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, dell-poweredge, network-printer, roaming-profile

Sorry for the long question above, i wasn;t sure what might be the best way to word it. 
I have a Dell poweredge R720 running Win SBS 2011, roaming profiles and folder redirection are not currently setup.

I just took receipt of a brand new ricoh copier, part of the setup process involves me configuring the print driver for the user while they are logged in, the issue is that i work in a medical clinic so user's sign in on any available machine in the employee workroom, i need the settings i set for the user to follow them on whatever machine they sign into - i have heard this can be done with Group Policy and one person told me it might be roaming profiles that needs to be enabled.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? I have been trying to solve this for nearly 3 days and I can't find anything out there that gives me a half decent guide on how to do what i am looking to do or even a guide on how to enable roaming profiles in sbs 2011...

I'd also like your opinion on what is the easiest way to get this going, whether its just with GPO or with roaming profiles or both or maybe another solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Roaming profile will do the job as the printer configuration are in \HCU. Does the target machine are in all the same OS ?

Comment: Yes, all target machines have windows 7 professional.

Comment: Be aware your question isn't specific to SBS, but rather applies to Windows Server in general, and Windows Server 2008 R2 in specific since that's the actual underlying OS of SBS 2011.

Comment: @Twisty - So, looking up how to setup roaming profiles on win server 2008 r2 would be the best option? When i open SBS console (advanced) I only see options for folder redirection and not for roaming profiles, I only see a "Profile path" option under active directory users & computers and i am assuming that is how i will generate roaming profiles for specific users?

Comment: I said what I said so you know you can expand your search for solutions beyond SBS 2011.  You cannot set up roaming profiles through the SBS Wizards. You'll need to set them up manually, just as you would if you weren't running SBS 2011.  The TechNet article [Deploy Roaming User Profiles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649079(v=ws.11).aspx) should get you well on your way.

Comment: @Twisty Thank you very much for your help. It is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xBcU8qKop8k), great how-to on how to enable roaming profile on windows server 2008 r2.

In resume; In your ADDC's console you select the user you want roaming profile, add the profile location and you make sure the location is setup correctly to handle the profile.

A good guide there too; [Deploy Roaming User Profiles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649079(v=ws.11).aspx)